# Changing Laravel MYSQL to utf8mb4 for Emoji Support in Existing Database

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5.3, emoji, laravel-migrations

I am using **Laravel 5.3** and I have already set-up my production server. All DB Migrations were already created using the following database config:

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],
```

But now, some of my users had reported that they get an error when they try to save a form that has emoji  icons in them. After searching I found out that I need to set the mysql charset to `utf8mb4` for this to work so my config should have been something like this instead:

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],
```

Since this is in a production server, I cannot do `migrate:refresh`. So my questions are:

1. How can I change my existing database I created using laravel migration to use `utf8mb4` instead of `utf8` and also update laravel on the same? Is there an easier way to do this?
2. If the above is possible, am I better off setting `utf8mb4` for all tables or only use that for the 2 table columns where I will really be using emoji.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5.4 upgrade, converting to utf4mb from utf8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42704637/laravel-5-4-upgrade-converting-to-utf4mb-from-utf8)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. Use raw mysql query to write the update table migration script and run `php artisan migrate` command

   ```
    use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

    class UpdateTableCharset extends Migration {

        /**
         * Run the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function up() {
                DB::unprepared('ALTER TABLE `table_name` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4');
        }

        /**
         * Reverse the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function down() {
                DB::unprepared('ALTER TABLE `table_name` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8');
        }
    }
   ```
2. My personal preference, update table. I don't have proof to say it is better

Note: You still have to keep the database config to `utf8mb4`.

Answer (score 11):

Based on @insomniak-dev answer, but will only shrink varchar when they exceed limits AND are used in an index.  Otherwise, they are converted, but size is left as is.  If a column will be shrunk, it then checks if any data will be truncated.

This also handles all text types and batches all conversions for each table into a single statement for speed.

Dryrun flag outputs usable sql instead of applying directly.

```
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    $dryRun = true;
    $this->convertDb('mysql', 'utf8mb4', 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci', $dryRun);
    $this->convertDb('archive', 'utf8mb4', 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci', $dryRun);
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    $dryRun = true;
    $this->convertDb('archive', 'utf8', 'utf8_unicode_ci', $dryRun);
    $this->convertDb('mysql', 'utf8', 'utf8_unicode_ci', $dryRun);
}

private function convertDb($connection, $charset, $collate, $dryRun)
{
    $dbName = config("database.connections.{$connection}.database");

    $varchars = \DB::connection($connection)
        ->select(\DB::raw("select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where DATA_TYPE = 'varchar' and (CHARACTER_SET_NAME != '{$charset}' or COLLATION_NAME != '{$collate}') AND TABLE_SCHEMA = '{$dbName}'"));
    // Check if shrinking field size will truncate!
    $skip = [];  // List of table.column that will be handled manually
    $indexed = [];
    if ($charset == 'utf8mb4') {
        $error = false;
        foreach($varchars as $t) {
            if ($t->CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH > 191) {
                $key = "{$t->TABLE_NAME}.{$t->COLUMN_NAME}";

                // Check if column is indexed
                $index = \DB::connection($connection)
                    ->select(\DB::raw("SHOW INDEX FROM `{$t->TABLE_NAME}` where column_name = '{$t->COLUMN_NAME}'"));
                $indexed[$key] = count($index) ? true : false;

                if (count($index)) {
                    $result = \DB::connection($connection)
                        ->select(\DB::raw("select count(*) as `count` from `{$t->TABLE_NAME}` where length(`{$t->COLUMN_NAME}`) > 191"));
                    if ($result[0]->count > 0) {
                        echo "-- DATA TRUNCATION: {$t->TABLE_NAME}.{$t->COLUMN_NAME}({$t->CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH}) => {$result[0]->count}" . PHP_EOL;
                        if (!in_array($key, $skip)) {
                            $error = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if ($error) {
            throw new \Exception('Aborting due to data truncation');
        }
    }

    $query = "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0";
    $this->dbExec($query, $dryRun, $connection);

    $query = "ALTER SCHEMA {$dbName} DEFAULT CHARACTER SET {$charset} DEFAULT COLLATE {$collate}";
    $this->dbExec($query, $dryRun, $connection);

    $tableChanges = [];
    foreach($varchars as $t) {
        $key = "{$t->TABLE_NAME}.{$t->COLUMN_NAME}";
        if (!in_array($key, $skip)) {
            if ($charset == 'utf8mb4' && $t->CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH > 191 && $indexed["{$t->TABLE_NAME}.{$t->COLUMN_NAME}"]) {
                $tableChanges["{$t->TABLE_NAME}"][] = "CHANGE `{$t->COLUMN_NAME}` `{$t->COLUMN_NAME}` VARCHAR(191) CHARACTER SET {$charset} COLLATE {$collate}";
                echo "-- Shrinking: {$t->TABLE_NAME}.{$t->COLUMN_NAME}({$t->CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH})" . PHP_EOL;
            } else if ($charset == 'utf8' && $t->CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH == 191) {
                $tableChanges["{$t->TABLE_NAME}"][] = "CHANGE `{$t->COLUMN_NAME}` `{$t->COLUMN_NAME}` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET {$charset} COLLATE {$collate}";
                echo "-- Expanding: {$t->TABLE_NAME}.{$t->COLUMN_NAME}({$t->CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH})";
            } else {
                $tableChanges["{$t->TABLE_NAME}"][] = "CHANGE `{$t->COLUMN_NAME}` `{$t->COLUMN_NAME}` VARCHAR({$t->CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH}) CHARACTER SET {$charset} COLLATE {$collate}";
            }
        }
    }

    $texts = \DB::connection($connection)
        ->select(\DB::raw("select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where DATA_TYPE like '%text%' and (CHARACTER_SET_NAME != '{$charset}' or COLLATION_NAME != '{$collate}') AND TABLE_SCHEMA = '{$dbName}'"));
    foreach($texts as $t) {
        $tableChanges["{$t->TABLE_NAME}"][] = "CHANGE `{$t->COLUMN_NAME}` `{$t->COLUMN_NAME}` {$t->DATA_TYPE} CHARACTER SET {$charset} COLLATE {$collate}";
    }

    $tables = \DB::connection($connection)
        ->select(\DB::raw("select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_COLLATION != '{$collate}' and TABLE_SCHEMA = '{$dbName}';"));
    foreach($tables as $t) {
        $tableChanges["{$t->TABLE_NAME}"][] = "CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET {$charset} COLLATE {$collate}";
        $tableChanges["{$t->TABLE_NAME}"][] = "DEFAULT CHARACTER SET={$charset} COLLATE={$collate}";
    }

    foreach ($tableChanges as $table => $changes) {
        $query = "ALTER TABLE `{$table}` ".implode(",\n", $changes);
        $this->dbExec($query, $dryRun, $connection);
    }

    $query = "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1";
    $this->dbExec($query, $dryRun, $connection);

    echo "-- {$dbName} CONVERTED TO {$charset}-{$collate}" . PHP_EOL;
}

private function dbExec($query, $dryRun, $connection)
{
    if ($dryRun) {
        echo $query . ';' . PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        \DB::connection($connection)->getPdo()->exec($query);
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked great for me, but I had some views that needed to be excluded after getting `General error: 1347 'table_name' is not BASE TABLE`. You can change the column conversion to include `INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t ON c.TABLE_CATALOG = t.TABLE_CATALOG AND c.TABLE_SCHEMA = t.TABLE_SCHEMA AND c.TABLE_NAME = t.TABLE_NAME AND t.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'` and change the table conversion to include `WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE_TABLE'`.

Answer (score 7):

for anyone willing to achieve this on the whole database i found myself needing such a script :

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;

class ChangeDbCharset extends Migration
{

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        $charset = "utf8mb4";
        $collate = $charset."_unicode_ci";
        $dbName = Config::get('database.connections.'.Config::get('database.default').'.database');
        $query = "ALTER SCHEMA $dbName DEFAULT CHARACTER SET $charset DEFAULT COLLATE $collate;\n"; 
        DB::connection()->getPdo()->exec($query);

        $dbName = Config::get('database.connections.'.Config::get('database.default').'.database');
        $result = DB::select(DB::raw('show tables'));
        $test = DB::select(DB::raw("select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where DATA_TYPE = 'varchar' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = '$dbName';"));
        //var_dump($test);
        foreach($test as $t)
        {
            $query = "ALTER TABLE $t->TABLE_NAME CHANGE $t->COLUMN_NAME $t->COLUMN_NAME VARCHAR(191) CHARACTER SET $charset COLLATE $collate; \n";
            echo $query;
            DB::connection()->getPdo()->exec($query);
        }
        $test = DB::select(DB::raw("select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where DATA_TYPE = 'text' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = '$dbName';"));
        foreach($test as $t)
        {
            $query = "ALTER TABLE $t->TABLE_NAME CHANGE $t->COLUMN_NAME $t->COLUMN_NAME TEXT CHARACTER SET $charset COLLATE $collate; \n";
            echo $query;
            DB::connection()->getPdo()->exec($query);
        }


        $result = DB::select(DB::raw('show tables'));
        foreach($result as $r)
        {
            foreach($r as $k => $t)
            {
                $query = "ALTER TABLE `$t` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET $charset COLLATE $collate; \n";
                echo $query;
                DB::connection()->getPdo()->exec($query);
            }
        }
        echo "DB CHARSET set to $charset , $collate";
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        $charset = "utf8";
        $collate = $charset."_unicode_ci";
        $dbName = Config::get('database.connections.'.Config::get('database.default').'.database');
        $query = "ALTER SCHEMA $dbName DEFAULT CHARACTER SET $charset DEFAULT COLLATE $collate;\n"; 
        DB::connection()->getPdo()->exec($query);

        $dbName = Config::get('database.connections.'.Config::get('database.default').'.database');
        $result = DB::select(DB::raw('show tables'));
        $test = DB::select(DB::raw("select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where DATA_TYPE = 'varchar' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = '$dbName';"));
        //var_dump($test);
        foreach($test as $t)
        {
            $query = "ALTER TABLE $t->TABLE_NAME CHANGE $t->COLUMN_NAME $t->COLUMN_NAME VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET $charset COLLATE $collate; \n";
            echo $query;
            DB::connection()->getPdo()->exec($query);
        }
        $test = DB::select(DB::raw("select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where DATA_TYPE = 'text' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = '$dbName';"));
        foreach($test as $t)
        {
            $query = "ALTER TABLE $t->TABLE_NAME CHANGE $t->COLUMN_NAME $t->COLUMN_NAME TEXT CHARACTER SET $charset COLLATE $collate; \n";
            echo $query;
            DB::connection()->getPdo()->exec($query);
        }


        $result = DB::select(DB::raw('show tables'));
        foreach($result as $r)
        {
            foreach($r as $k => $t)
            {
                $query = "ALTER TABLE `$t` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET $charset COLLATE $collate; \n";
                echo $query;
                DB::connection()->getPdo()->exec($query);
            }
        }
        echo "DB CHARSET set to $charset , $collate";
    }

}
```

Comment: Using VARCHAR($t->CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH) instead of VARCHAR(191) seems better