# Changing Laravel MYSQL to utf8mb4 when migrating

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I using Laravel 5.7 and I would like to change my current mysqldb to utf8mb4.

Find below my migration:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateTickDataTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('tick_data', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('coin_basis_id')->nullable();

            //...

            $table->timestamp('open_time')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('close_time')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('exchange_timestamp');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

}

Basically I would like to `ALTER` the table after its creation, however I get the following error when adding `DB::unprepared('ALTER TABLE tick_data CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4');` to the `up()` function:

> default character set utf8mb4 collate 'u tf8mb4_unicode_ci')

When is the best place to run this statement?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5.4 upgrade, converting to utf4mb from utf8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42704637/laravel-5-4-upgrade-converting-to-utf4mb-from-utf8)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could try this to modify the table after its creation:

```
Schema::table('tick_data', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('table_name') // Name of the colum
                ->nullable() // must not fill
                ->after('exchange_timestamp'); // after the column "exchange_timestamp"
});
```

Comment: Thx for your reply! When would you run: `DB::unprepared('ALTER TABLE tick_data CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4');`

Comment: I dont think you would need to run this line, but I guess you could try to insert DB::raw('ALTER TABLE tick_data CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4') inside the DB::unprepared()